# NodeJs PostgresQl: Supplied 2 Parameters But Prepared Statement "" Requires 0

Tags: node.js, postgresql

I have the following function which I call from my controller:

```
async function insertUser(user_name, icon_link) {
    
    await pool.query("DO $$BEGIN IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM targets WHERE user_name = $1 ) THEN UPDATE targets SET icon_link = $2 , complaints  = complaints + 1; ELSE INSERT INTO targets(user_name, icon_link, complaints) VALUES( $1 , $2 , 0); END IF; END; $$;", data);
}
```

I get the following error when I try to call it:

```
const message = name === 'notice' ? new messages_1.NoticeMessage(length, messageValue) : new messages_1.DatabaseError(messageValue, length, name);
                                                                                                 ^

error: bind message supplies 2 parameters, but prepared statement "" requires 0
    at Parser.parseErrorMessage (/Users/user/project/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:287:98)
    at Parser.handlePacket (/Users/user/project/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:126:29)
    at Parser.parse (/Users/user/project/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:39:38)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/Users/user/project/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/index.js:11:42)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:512:28)
    at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:324:12)
    at readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:297:9)
    at Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:234:10)
    at TCP.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:190:23) {
```

This was working fine until it suddenly stopped working for some reason that I cannot understand.

I know the issue is not because of the query itself because the same issue persists on my other queries as well. Also variables are passing on fine, I have checked it while debugging.

I tried passing the parameters like this:

```
async function insertUser(user_name, icon_link) {
    
    await pool.query({text: 'DO $$BEGIN IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM targets WHERE user_name = $1 ) THEN UPDATE targets SET icon_link = $2 , complaints  = complaints + 1; ELSE INSERT INTO targets(user_name, icon_link, complaints) VALUES( $1 , $2 , 0); END IF; END; $$;', values: [user_name, icon_link]});
}
```

It didn't work.

I also tried passing them by adding ' to the string parameters:

```
async function insertUser(user_name, icon_link) {
    
    await pool.query("DO $$BEGIN IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM targets WHERE user_name = '$1' ) THEN UPDATE targets SET icon_link = '$2' , complaints  = complaints + 1; ELSE INSERT INTO targets(user_name, icon_link, complaints) VALUES( '$1' , '$2' , 0); END IF; END; $$;", data);
}
```

It didn't also work for obvious reasons.

Edit:
I also discovered that If I pass no variables:

```
const res = await client.query('DO $$ BEGIN IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM targets WHERE user_name = $1 ) THEN UPDATE targets SET icon_link = $2 , complaints  = complaints + 1; ELSE INSERT INTO targets(user_name, icon_link, complaints) VALUES( $1 , $2 , 0); END IF; END $$;');
```

I get:

```
error: there is no parameter $1
```

Comment: Can you show a `console.log(data)`?

Comment: @lpizzinidev it's `[ 'testuser', 'https://test.com/testuser' ]`, db is active and this function was updating the db, for some reason it has stopped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Formatting the query before hand solves the issue, but I think passing the parameters should be working. You must use ` instead of " for this to work.

```
return await pool.query(`DO $$ BEGIN IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM targets WHERE user_name = \'${user_name}\' ) THEN UPDATE targets SET icon_link = \'${icon_link}\' , complaints  = complaints + 1; ELSE INSERT INTO targets(user_name, icon_link, complaints) VALUES(\'${user_name}\' , \'${icon_link}\' , 0); END IF; END $$;`);
```